# Why does this animation go back and forth?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new to animation in Android and am performing some tests first.

So, I created this Activity

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            imageView.animate()
                .translationX(imageView2.x - imageView.x)
                .translationY(imageView2.y - imageView.y)
                .start()
        }

    }
```

With this layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="232dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="296dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When I click on the button it animates the first image perfectly to the second image.

What I don't understand is why clicking the button again animates it back to its original position.
It seems to know where the image was and is now and to reverse animation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an example with values that are easy to reason about:

- The first `ImageView` is at (50, 50)
- The second `ImageView` is at (100, 100)

When you press the button the first time, the `translationX` property will animate from its current value (`0`), to `100 - 50 = 50`. Same for the `translationY` property.

"Translation" is relative. So we add the translation to the view's original coordinates. `50 + 50 = 100`, so the first view slides over to (100, 100), the same position as the second view.

- The first `ImageView` is at (100, 100), with translation values of 50 and 50.
- The second `ImageView` is still at (100, 100)

It is important to realize that the first view's `x` and `y` properties are updated, but the `translationX` and `translationY` properties "remember" that they are non-zero. So now the first view is at (100, 100), but it remembers that it has translation values of 50 and 50.

Now you click the button again. We run the same calculation as before, but this time the starting values for `translationX` (and y) are not zero, they're `50`. So the `translationX` property will animate from its current value (`50`), to `100 - 100 = 0`. In essence, we're "resetting" the translation values back to zero. So the view slides back to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually logical and pretty straight forward.

When you click for the first time, imageView translates to [(232-52)x , (192-80)y] which is (180, 112).

Then when you click for the second time, imageView translates from (180, 112) to [(232-180)x, (192-112)y] which is (52,80).

So it returns to its old position.

Comment: So, translationX is HOW much to move or WHERE to move? Cos if it is how much to move then surely the second case should keep going down and right. OTOH, if it is where to move then how come it does move to the second view on the first call.

Comment: It is WHERE to move. And everytime it moves, it updates its coordinates. So when you clicked for second time, imageView's location won't be the same before you clicked for first time.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the second time you call the animation both the imageView's X and Y positions are the same hence the difference is 0 and the translationX and translationY are reset to 0.